# 500 Error With WSGI in Django

Tags: django, wsgi

I'm deploying my first ever Django project and I get the feeling I'm very close, but just need some help getting over the line. Here's the problem:

My httpd.conf changes look like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite

<Directory /home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

So far so good, the "hello world" script in wsgi.py runs just fine. The problem comes when I use the Django doc-recommended wsgi script:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tncsite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This causes a 500 error:

```
File "/home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite/wsgi.py", line 10, in ?
mod_wsgi (pid=15494): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=15494): Target WSGI script '/home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

All of the support I've seen on the error relates back to bad installations in apache, not finding modules etc, which can't be the case if "hello world" is running.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

After restarting on a fresh server, I've managed to move things forward slightly. The good news is that python and WSGI seem to be playing nice, the bad is that I'm now getting a different kind of 500 error.

The only error I'm getting back in the log is:
    "[Mon Dec 05 18:22:45 2011] [error] [client ip] mod_wsgi (pid=19804): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite/apache/wsgi.py'."

The Hello World script still runs fine, the trigger for the error is the final line:

```
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I've set all directories containing the project from frontend/ down to 777 and I've added a daemon process as myself:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/apache/extramodules/mod_wsgi.so
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

WSGIDaemonProcess miketnc processes=2 maximum-requests=500 threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup miketnc

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite/apache/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Anyone please able to advise further on how to get this working?

Comment: is there any output in the error log?  It's not clear 'why' your script could not be imported.

Comment: There would have been a traceback and error message after the line saying 'cannot be loaded as Python module' in the error log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

I didn't realise that the error log in Cpanel is a tiny fraction of the error log Apache outputs. Once I viewed the Apache logs, the problem was obvious. In this case it was MySQLdb not being set up properly.

I worked through it, making some adjustments around .python-eggs, and all is now well.

Thanks for the responses and in particular thank you Graham for the work you've put into WSGI.

Comment: Indeed, I have been struggling getting WSGI to work, too.  When I found the Apache error log, it really did help!  I am attempting to use Microsoft SQLServer, though.  It's a bit more problematic since it's not officially supported by Django.

Comment: yep. Please check your db connection is setup correct & modules are installed. Had the same issue with psycopg2. #Win

Answer (score 5):

In your case:

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite
```

is redundant, as your are setting sys.path in the WSGI script file.

What you are missing though is adding the parent directory of the site:

```
sys.path.append('/home/miketnc/frontend')
```

This is in addition to the existing line adding '/home/miketnc/frontend/tncsite'.

Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

and watch:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

which talk about paths and permissions.

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks for the response. I viewed the resources as you suggested and I'm closer, but still not quite there. I added the parent directory path as suggested, to no avail. After poking around further, I realised the 500 error comes from:

    import django.core.handlers.wsgi

Django is installed in python 2.7, apache is running 2.4. So looking at [link](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Multiple_Python_Versions) I can see I probably need to change the envvars file, using:

    PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
    export PATH

I'm not 100% sure what I need to be putting

Comment: there though. Would it be something like:

PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7
export PATH

?

Comment: You have to recompile mod_wsgi to use Python 2.7. You can't just tell it to use a different Python version than what it was built for.

Comment: Thanks Graham. I've started afresh with a new server and installs which has covered this. Please see the update above for the current problem.